# Delete all CSS in one skid

Tags: jquery, css

how can i delete all CSS-stylings in one skid from a specific Selector. Is there something like .unstyle()? :P

Thanks

Comment: I am not aware of any standard jquery API to do such a thing but you may try this plugin: http://benjaminmock.de/jquery-css-reset-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 functions [.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) :

```
$("element").removeAttr("style"); 
// removes style attribute from element like
// <div style="..."></div>
$("element").removeAttr('class'); 
// removes class attribute from element like
// <div class="..."></div>
```

and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/):

```
$("element").removeClass("class name");
// removes one or multiple classes
$("element").removeClass(function(index,class){});
// with a callback function for more control
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are styling in inline style you can remove that attribute:

```
$("#Element").removeAttr("style")
```

and if you want to remove css class use:

```
$("#Element").removeAttr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

The question you are asking is a little weird. There are almost no default stylings in CSS. Different browsers add default styling to their pages but they are not the same. So if you want to "unstyle" something, you have to define what you consider is "unstyled". Do you get me? When that definition is done the hard part is over.

Comment: Yes i got you. When i style a div like "border: 1px solid black" i want to delete this style, what means it should look like the way it looks before i added the border styling.